# How to get the values of input fields of multiple classes using jquery

Tags: jquery

My desired output for the below code should be:

```
a-b-c-d,e-f-g-h,i-j-k-l
```

Note the comma instead of `-` after `d` and `h`.

But the below code results in

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l,a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l,a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l,
```

I tried searching across stack overflow, but did not came across this type of question. Could someone please help me, please do not mark this question as repititive.

```html
<div class="test1 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="a" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz"  value="b" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="c" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="d" />
</div>

<div class="test2 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="e" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="f" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="g" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="h" />
</div>

<div class="test3 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="i" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="j" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="k" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="l" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class='submit'>

  <p class='count'></p> 
 <p class='test'></p> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        var count = $('.yes').length
        $('.count').text(count);
       
        var texts = "";
        var i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
        texts += $(".xyz").map(function() { return this.value; })
                                   .get().join('-') + ",";
        i++;
    }

    $('.test').text(texts);    

    });
    

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `.yes` elements, building the array of their `.xyz` elements and joining it with `-`, then join the result with `,`:

```
var texts = $(".yes").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(".xyz").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join("-");
}).get().join(",");
```

Live Example:

```js
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var count = $('.yes').length
    $('.count').text(count);
    
    var texts = $(".yes").map(function() {
        return $(this).find(".xyz").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join("-");
    }).get().join(",");

    $('.test').text(texts);

});

// a-b-c-d,e-f-g-h,i-j-k-l
```

```html
<div class="test1 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="a" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz"  value="b" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="c" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="d" />
</div>

<div class="test2 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="e" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="f" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="g" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="h" />
</div>

<div class="test3 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="i" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="j" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="k" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="l" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class='submit'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <p class='count'></p> 
 <p class='test'></p> 

<p style="font-weight: bold;" class="time text-center"></p>
```

More:

- [`jQuery.fn.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`jQuery.fn.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It's working..Love from India

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var texts = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < count) {
    texts += $(".xyz").map(function() { return this.value; })
                               .get().join('-') + ",";
    i++;
}
```

just write

```
var texts = ''
$('.yes').each(function() {
  textx += $(this).children('.xyz')
                  .map(function() { return this.value; })
                  .get().join('-') + ','
})
```

Comment: This doesn't generate my desired output i.e a-b-c-d,e-f-g-h,i-j-k-l your code generates a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-j-k-l

Answer (score 0):

It's happened because of your +=, which means it will append the result every iteration.
My solution is to write only =.

```html
<div class="test1 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="a" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz"  value="b" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="c" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="d" />
</div>

<div class="test2 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="e" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="f" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="g" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="h" />
</div>

<div class="test3 yes">
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="i" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="j" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="k" />
 <input type="text" class="xyz" value="l" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class='submit'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <p class='count'></p> 
 <p class='test'></p> 

<p style="font-weight: bold;" class="time text-center"></p>

<script>
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        var count = $('.yes').length
        $('.count').text(count);
       
        var texts = "";
        var i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
        texts = $(".xyz").map(function() { return this.value; })
                                   .get().join('-') + ",";
        i++;
    }

    $('.test').text(texts);    

    });
    

</script>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. To make the answer useful, say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: Yes, I explain that :)

Comment: your code is resulting in  a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l, whereas what I need is  a-b-c-d,e-f-g-h,i-j-k-l